# Should I useIPC or remote in electron?

Tags: electron

I want to minimize the screen on a button click. This click handler is inside a render process. I've seen a lot of possible solutions that use the remote object from electron and directly minimize the window. A different solution would be to send an event using ipcRenderer to main to then close it via the main process. Which solution should I use (if there even is an advantage/disadvantage to either one)?

I've seen a lot of comments about security in electron (specially when using remote), so that's why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 3):

Electron core team strongly discourage to use remote (https://medium.com/@nornagon/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31) and it will be deprecated from core by moving to user land module. New ipc api surface via `invoke` handler should be able to provide sufficiently enough conveniences to use ipc.